# How to use jquery .value() function

Tags: jquery

Hello trying to write jquery that when l select a direction from my html drop down menu it provides an alert saying the name of direction l chose. Tried the below code but seems to not work

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    //selection for combobox...
    $('#mydirection').change(function (e){
        doOnChange(e)
    })

});

function doOnChange(myObj){
    if (typeof console == "E"){
        console.log("Change on selection");
        console.log(myObj);
    }
    alert("You chose East");

    if (typeof console == "W"){
        console.log("Change on selection");
        console.log(myObj);
    }
    alert("You chose west");

    if (typeof console == "N"){
        console.log("Change on selection");
        console.log(myObj);
    }
    alert("You chose north");

    if (typeof console == "S"){
        console.log("Change on selection");
        console.log(myObj);
    }
    alert("You chose south");
}
function updateStatusBox(img, msg) {
    document.getElementById('statuscaption').innerHTML = msg;
    document.getElementById('event_image').src = img;
}
```

```html
<p>Please select a direction:<br/>
    <select id="mydirection"  name="direction">
      <option value="N">North</option>
      <option value="S">South</option>
      <option value="E">East</option>
      <option value="W">West</option>
    </select>
  </p>
```

Comment: How exactly does it _not work_? What happens vs what do you expect to happen? Are there any errors reported? Your question snippet is missing jQuery, do you have the same issue in your own code?

Comment: You have a lot of errors. Why are you comparing `typeof console` to E, W, etc (`typeof console` is **always** `"object"`)? You're passing the event `e` as the `myObj` argument but you never use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you!!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //selection for combobox...
    $('#mydirection').change(function (e){
        doOnChange($('option:selected',this))
    })

});

function doOnChange(myObj){
    console.log(myObj.text())
}
function updateStatusBox(img, msg) {
    document.getElementById('statuscaption').innerHTML = msg;
    document.getElementById('event_image').src = img;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Please select a direction:<br/>
    <select id="mydirection"  name="direction">
      <option value="N">North</option>
      <option value="S">South</option>
      <option value="E">East</option>
      <option value="W">West</option>
    </select>
  </p>
```